# DataService в MVVM приложении

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, mvvm-light

Добрый день. Имею крупный проект на MVVM Light. Используется подход Database-First на Entity Framework. Есть класс DataService.В этом файле 5809 строк! Хочу как-то это дело поправить. Хорошо ли будет, если я разделю DataService на несколько различных сервисов? Может стоит посмотреть в сторону паттернов Repository или UnitOfWork но наслышан, что они довольно бессмыслены с EF. К сожалению, нет крутых дядек девелоперов в нашей организации, поэтому подсказать некому.

DataService - сервис доступа к данным из БД. Использует EF. Привожу для примера один релевантный метод в DataService.

```
public firma GetFirmById(int id_firm, params string[] includes)
    {
        using (var clientEntities = new ClientEntities(Application.Current.Properties["connectionStringForClient"].ToString(), false))
        {
            DbQuery<firma> query = clientEntities.firms;
            foreach (var include in includes)
                query = query.Include(include);

            return query.First(f => f.id_firm == id_firm);
        }
    }
```

Comment: название класса DataService не говорит ни о чем. у вас там может быть все что угодно. уточните вопрос. покажите пример кода метода из DataService. но вообще я бы посоветовал попробовать разбить на классы по корневым сущностям, для начала.

Comment: @PashaPash обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Количество строк не говорит о количестве публичных методов. Если сроки позволяют, то конечно можно потратить время и разнести методы по более узкоспециализированным классам. Если класс чужой, то лучше вообще не трогать, чтобы потом  не отвечать за чужие проблемы (автор класса ведь потом скажет что все отлично работало до вашего рефакторинга) . В этом случае, максимум - разнесите внутри класса по тематическим регионам.

Comment: Автор кода здесь уже не работает. Меня больше интересует как это делается в других крупных проектах. Неужели повсюду, где используется MVVM используется один класс на все виды доступа к БД? Ведь есть проекты и крупней нашего.

Comment: Не могу назвать свои проекты особо крупными. Вот был один проект с четыремя параллельными базами. ~40, ~30, 5, 5 таблиц соответственно. Архитектура строилась следующим образом: SQL<=>WCF(с EF)=<WPF MVVM>    Правда базы в основном уже существовали, поэтому подход был Data-First. С помощью EF получил четыре набора классов на каждую таблицу и по новому методу на каждую хранимую процедуру.  Да - это месиво! Но никто не мешает разделить все это богатство в интерфейсе, где описываются контракты WCF. Тогда клиент WCF будет иметь доступ к уже структурированным как мне нужно методам и данным.

Comment: Кстати классы WCF уже вполне можно использовать в качестве моделей для MVVM без прокси-классов.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь уместен [паттерн "репозиторий"](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/45818/).

Суть паттерна в том, что для каждого типа создаётся отдельный класс-репозиторий с операциями, касающимися этого типа. Чаще всего это CRUD + специфичные операции.

Например, FirmaRepository с методами Create, GetById, Get (если нужно несколько), Update, Delete.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/53500)

Comment: Дополнил ответ, хотя искренне считаю, что он в этом не нуждался. Паттерн "репозиторий" очень широко распространён и эта конкретная ссылка ведёт всего лишь в верхний результат гугла по этому запросу.